# Linearly independent set with dense span and Schauder basis.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space. A [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) of $V$ is a sequence $(v_n)$ in $V$ such that for each $v$ in $V$ there is a unique sequence $(a_n)$ of complex numbers such that $v=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nv_n$.

Now suppose that there is a linearly independent countable set $S\subseteq V$ such that $\text{span}(S)$ is dense in $V$.

**My question is** if one can necessarily find a Schauder basis of $V$ in $\text{span}(S)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V=C[0,1]$ with sup norm and $S=\{1,x,x^{2},...\}$. Then your conditions are satisfied. If there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that every continuous function is a sum $\sum a_np_n$ (the series converging in sup norm) then every continuous function would be analytic, in particular a $C^{\infty}$ function,  which is false.